# Is there a list of all XFixes cursor types?

Tags: linux, x11

I've recently been dabbling into X11 and wanted to retrieve information about the current mouse cursor state. I managed to get the cursor type, yet I didn't manage to find a list of all cursor atoms/names and their actual design, maybe because I only looked in the X11 files.

I used XFixes library and the `XFixesGetCursorName` (which gives you the ID, name and atom (the latter two being unique). I don't really mind whether it's done with name or atom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of all of the standard cursors is in `X11/cursorfont.h` but it's encoded.  Here's an extract of that file on my machine:

```
#define XC_cross_reverse 32
#define XC_crosshair 34
#define XC_diamond_cross 36
```

The corresponding names are `cross_reverse`, `crosshair` and `diamond_cross`.